# Error on another device

Tags: android

Well I have an application, a small social network, which in my aparelo android version 4.4.2 runs perfectly, now testing other devices, after part of the facebook login with the application closes. other devices have previous versions (4.1.2), (4.0), was wondering how it is possible to verify this error because I tried to see these versions in the emulator and the application ran perfectly well.

Who can give me a hint, thank you!

Comment: What would you do if this would have happened on your device? Debug it? Do that on the other device.

Comment: It's hard to say. Different device manufacturers customize the OS to different degrees. While in theory all applications will run the same, in practice there are issues. Use one of the log reporting tools so you can see what's going on on each device.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to android, but how do I see the error at the other apparatus in case I to getting the apk folder and placing it manually and not making direct debug.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the stack traces provided in the Developer Console, or look into using [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra).

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics: http://try.crashlytics.com/ Easier to integrate, equally effective